# jquery if value is not empty add active class

Tags: jquery

I have input where is label on it (Like placeholder), if i write into input then label gets class="active". (This works)

But if it has already value="test" then it must have automatically label class="active".

My code:

```
$('.data').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        label = $this.prev('label');

    if ($this.val() === '') {
        label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
        label.addClass('active highlight');
    }

    if ($this.val() === '') {
        label.removeClass('active highlight');
    } else {
        label.removeClass('highlight');
    }

    if ($this.val() === '') {
        label.removeClass('highlight');
    } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
        label.addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

and this code works with only keyup.

```
$('.data').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        label = $this.prev('label');

    if (e.type === 'keyup') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
            label.addClass('active highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'blur') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('active highlight');
        } else {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
        }
    } else if (e.type === 'focus') {
        if ($this.val() === '') {
            label.removeClass('highlight');
        } else if ($this.val() !== '') {
            label.addClass('highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

At the moment if input value="test" and if I click input then it gives class active, but I need it adds automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the `keyup` event immediately after page load to add `active` class automatically like following.

```
$('.data').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
    //your code
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I click input then it gives class active, but I need it added automatically.

That's simple, just fire one of the events you're watching for:

```
$('.data').find('input,textarea').trigger('keyup')
```

Meanwhile, your function is unnecessarily repetitive; it's not necessary to separately handle every one of the three events you're watching, since they're all doing the same thing.  You could reduce that to

```
$('.data').find('input, textarea').on('keyup blur focus', function (e) {
  var $this = $(this),
      label = $this.prev('label');
  if ($this.val() === '') {
    label.removeClass('active highlight');
  } else {
    label.addClass('active highlight');
  }
}).trigger('keyup');
```

...or better yet just use the `change` event instead, as that's the most relevant for what you're trying to do.